# Dynamic instance-level permissions with Apache Shiro

Tags: java, authorization, shiro, dropwizard

I am creating a REST service in Java using [Dropwizard](http://dropwizard.io/) in combination with [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) for authentication and authorization. I extended JdbcRealm in order to make Shiro use my PostgreSQL database (which I access through Hibernate). Authentication works well. Creating group-level permissions is also very easy. Unfortunately, I was not able to find an idiomatic way to bind certain resource instances to specific users (subjects). I know that Shiro provides support for [instance-level access control](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authz/permission/WildcardPermission.html), but the documentation does not show a workflow which allows me to do the following:

- User Alice creates resource X
- User Bob should be allowed to read X, but not to write/delete it
- User Alice should have full read/write/delete access to X

Any hints or recommendations are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm investigating a similar problem where I have a multi tenancy requirement so I don't know who the tenant is at compile time, something like this type of permission string:

```
global:{tenant}:users:limited,c,r,u,d
```

You might want to take a look at [`PermissionResolver`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authz/permission/PermissionResolver.html) I found this page quite helpful [AuthorizationConfiguration](https://shiro.apache.org/authorization.html#Authorization-Configuringaglobal%7B%7BPermissionResolver%7D%7D) from the shiro docs, the shiro docs are a bit of a scattergun

Comment: I ended up doing it all programmatically using `Subject.checkPermission()` and a DAO for permissions in my database!